# Search for a word in file line by line in C programming

Tags: c, file, search, fgets, strstr

I am trying to write code to search for a word in a file line by line and print the line containing the word.
Functions `fgets` and `getline` didn't seem to work.

```
void FindWord(char *word , char *file){
   char *line ;
   line = (char*)malloc(1024) ;
   int fd ;
   fd = open(file , O_RDONLY );
   while (fgets(line , sizeof(line) ,fd )!= NULL)
   {
      if (strstr(line , word )!= NULL)
      {
         printf("%s",line);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: what functions can i use with open() that works as fgets() ?

Comment: 1) use fopen()  2) regarding malloc(), in C, do not cast the returned value  3) regarding malloc() always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure successful operaiton.  4) always check (!= NULL) the returned value from any open/fopen function call.  5) use fopen( filename, "r" ) then fgets and getline will work.

Comment: please read the manual for those functions you use in your code.  For instance, open() returns a small integer, but fgets and getline require a pointer to a file descriptor.

Comment: 'sizeof(line)' where line is declared by: 'char *line;' will return 4, not the number of bytes allocated by malloc()

Comment: @user3629249, to your first comment, point (1): `open` isn't bad to use. `fopen` is also using `open` inside it. `fopen` is just a library call, `open` is a system call. Both do the same job. Just that `fopen` is a bit easier to use. But you can't say that `fopen` is better than `open`. So your point is wrong.

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ,  I did not say that `open()` was bad to use, it just does not return what is needed by the call to `fgets()`   The OPs code is using fgets()`, which requires a POINTER to a file descriptor, but `open()` returns a small integer, not a POINTER to a file descriptor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1**

`fgets()` needs a `FILE*` not a file descriptor.

Change

```
 int fd ;
 fd = open(file , O_RDONLY );
```

to

```
 FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r");
```

and use `fp` as the argument to `fgets`.

**Problem 2**

`sizeof(line)` doesn't evaluate to `1024`, as you are probably expecting. It just evaluates to the size of a pointer, which is most likely `4` or `8`.

Change

```
while (fgets(line , sizeof(line) ,fd )!= NULL)
```

to

```
while (fgets(line , 1024, fp )!= NULL)
```

**Update**

Also, since you are hard coding 1024 in the call to `malloc`, you might as well use an array. Then, you can use `sizeof(line)`.

```
void FindWord(char *word , char *file){
   char line[1024] ;
   FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r") ;
   while (fgets(line , sizeof(line) , fp )!= NULL)
   {
      if (strstr(line , word )!= NULL)
      {
         printf("%s",line);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top of the file.

Comment: what other functions that works as fgets that can be used with open() ?

Comment: You can use `fread` but that function does not stop reading at the end of a line. It also does not add a terminating null character. `fgets` is your best option.

Comment: @Hadeel Read the documentation.  If a function takes an integer parameter (a file descriptor) to read, then you can pass it the integer returned from open.  If it takes a FILE *, you cannot.  But you can create a FILE * from the file descriptor with `fdopen`.  In other words, if you have a file descriptor `fd` and you want to use `fgets`, just do: `FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "r"); if( *fp != NULL ) { fgets(...,...,fp); ....}`

Comment: what if each line contains only one number that i should save in a array ? 
can i also use fgets ? what is the value for the size ?

Comment: @HadeelSwedan, you can continue to use 1024 for size. `fgets` will stop reading when it encounters newline characters. It won't read 1024 characters unless a line has 1024 or more characters.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are wrong.

- You should not use `open` and work with file descriptors, if you don't have to.
  Also,  `fgets` needs `FILE` as 3. argument, not file descriptor. Use `FILE` macro:

  ```
  FILE *f = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
  // Use f here
  fclose(f);
  ```
- Second, you allocated memory and never release it.

  ```
  char *line = malloc(1024 /* *sizeof(char)*/);
  //Some code here
  free(line);
  ```
- `sizeof(line)` returns size of pointer, not buffer size.
- `fgets(line , n , f)` <strike>reads `n` bytes, not line</strike>. It reads at most `n` bytes, stops on '\n' or EOF. Use `getline` instead.

  ```
  char *line_buffer = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  FILE *f = fopen(...);

  getline(&line_buffer, &n, f);
  //use here

  fclose(f);
  free(line_buffer);
  ```

All combined:

```
void FindWord(char *word , char *file){
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "r") ;
    while (getline(&line_buffer, &n, f) != -1)
    {
        if (strstr(line , word )!= NULL)
        {
             printf("%s",line);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(line);
}
```

Comment: fgets() will stop on a newline or a NUL byte, which ever is encountered first.